# PHP Syntax Error (Novice)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Can someone help me with a PHP line in Wordpress.

I just add the PHP `else` condition after the `if` in case that the site owner did not post a feature image. Please don't correct it but point me a hint so I can find the syntax error myself.

```
<a class="main_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
<?php if($feat_image){?>
<img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt="">
<?php } ?> 

<?php else() {?>
<img src="http://website.com/if_no_feat_image.jpg" alt="">
<?php } ?>

</a>
```

Comment: An `else` statement does have a requirement, it just does whatever the `if` statement doesn't do. You need to remove the `()` after the `else` statement in order for it to work. If you however want the `else` statement to have a condition change it to `elseif` then you can have the `()` to put the condition in.

Comment: OP: *Thank you* for asking for a hint so you could find the error itself, instead of asking for the code outright. That is are rare and welcome attitude from newbies indeed! Just for that, let me give you a bit of advice from a pro: If you've written any amount of working, practical code, you're a "real programmer". Inexperienced as of yet, but real. Many old coding vets even ask themselves if they're "real" - it isn't worth the emotional exhaustion. (I also bring that up b/c I edited it out of the question for brevity.)

Comment: On another note, in the future, please include the full text of the error or a proper description of the problem. It's vital, especially as code gets more complex. See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form:

```
<a class="main_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
    <?php if ($feat_image) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt="">
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="http://website.com/if_no_feat_image.jpg" alt="">
    <?php } ?>
</a>
```

and a more beautiful one:

```
<a class="main_img" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
    <?php if ($feat_image): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt="">
    <?php else: ?>
        <img src="http://website.com/if_no_feat_image.jpg" alt="">
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: So I add to change 
this : <?php else() {?>
  to : <?php } else { ?>

Comment: Still do not know why some people use { } in php code and some dont. Here is the best example with your correct form and more beautiful one.

Comment: Usually syntax with ```{}``` is for back-end. And syntax with ```:``` is for front-end (view (inside html)).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong for the `else` part. You don't need the parenthesis.

Change `<?php else() {?>`
to this: `<?php else {?>`